# Javascript join outputs string with comma despite seperator argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a rather weird issue. I have an array of html-code in string-format that I want to join together and insert into an existing element on my page.

The array looks something like this:

```
var sample_array = ['<div class="cld-event"><div class="cld-time">12:00</div><div class="cld-description">Some blabla</div></div>', '<div class="cld-event"><div class="cld-time">15:00</div><div class="cld-description">Some blabla</div></div>', ...];
```

When joining and inserting the array such as:

```
$(myelement).html(sample_array.join(''));
```

I weirdly enough get the individual html elements separated by commas, which I of course do not want.

Just logging the array join in the console also returns the elements separated by a comma. I already tried replacing the `''` argument in the join method with other strings such as `'+'`, but it doesn't help either, it's always the comma that shows up.

I linted the entire code and I have no errors. Has anybody every encountered something like this? I'm sure I'm making some very obvious and very stupid mistake here, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: your example works at console as expected

Comment: Just tried the example given on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nalum/yBGtr/)

Comment: I tried it in the console as well and it works, so it really is fairly weird.

Comment: Ok, I discovered the problem. Somewhere along the way I managed to turn the array into a two-dimensional array, thus the join behaved weirdly. Thanks to everyone that tried to help...

Comment: i had the same issue. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you are not including the commas in some way?like adding an extra set of quotes so that you only have one element of the array?

Because the only reason for this is that actually you are joining an array with only one element (so no join is performed and so join('+') is ignored)

what value has `sample_array.length`?

are you sure your array is not (notice the quotes at the beginning)

```
["'<div class="cld-event"><div class="cld-time">12:00</div><div class="cld-description">Some blabla</div></div>', '<div class="cld-event"><div class="cld-time">15:00</div><div class="cld-description">Some blabla</div></div>', ..."];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The array length is 2 (in theory it could be more, but I have only 2 elements in this specifc case), so it's not the problem you describe.

Comment: Ok, so then as Zanfa suggested post your full code because your problem is not replicable! :)

Answer (score 3):

I just had this issue myself. It's four years since you asked, but maybe some people like me will Google this answer and save themselves some time.

I was working with a string that I `split()` up into an array to modify some parts and then `join()` it back into a string. So basically, I started with

`var myNiftyStuff = 'My nifty stuff.';
myNiftyStuff = myNiftyStuff.split('');`

Here, `myNiftyStuff` starts life as a string. `split()` then changes it into an array.

Then whatever mods I wanted to work on happened in the array. When I tried to join my array, I was calling

`myNiftyStuff.join('');`

**Since `join()` isn't destructive, it was just returning itself but not modifying the variable.** But I didn't realize it, my linter wasn't barking, and nothing in the code looked off.

Then, I was passing my array to the page via jQuery (not sure if jQ matters here or not), which rendered it as a joined string using commas, which must be a default behavior.

I *should have* overwritten my variable like so

`myNiftyStuff = myNiftyStuff.join('');`

Now `myNiftyStuff` is updated with `join()`'s return value. When I add it to the page, it's a joined string, whereas before I was passing the array without realizing I hadn't saved the result of my `join()`.

Comment: Thanks mccambridge! Your contribution got my code working.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, it seems to happen when you have a 2 levels array(one inside of another), in my case it was being caused by Object.values(myObject).
I've solved it using lodash `_.flattenDeep`
you can see more details in its documentation:  https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flatten

Answer (score 0):

Works for me just as you'd expect. Mind throwing together a quick jsfiddle?

However, if you get the comas there, you must have them in your original array (did you split it from something else, or how did you generate the array?). Another possibility is that you might use a variable as the join argument, which somehow get's a wrong value.

You probably don't have an coma-delimited array, but `["<div></div>,<div></div>"]` that looks like an array of 2 elements, but really isn't.

Comment: I'm logging the original array before joining and there is no comma anywhere. I'm retrieving a bunch of events from the server via ajax, then I push each event in the form of an html-string into the array. That is the array that I'm trying to join thereafter. I would throw an example together, but if simply writing down an example array everything works as expected...

Comment: @ximi Well if you can't post or show us the code, you could fix it by not joining them and instead, loop through the array and create a jQuery object of each of the elements and append it to the myelement. It's a hack, but what you gonna do.

Comment: I prepared a fiddle that shows a little more of the process, but I don't think it actually adds anything new to the problem: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hYcsq/)

Comment: What I see from your code is that you have one gigantic error in the logic of asynchronous requests. It's very unlikely that you even get anything from eventGetter since it defines an empty array, does a request that should fill it and instantly returns the empty array, without waiting for the request to complete. When the request does finally finish, it assigns the results to an array nobody cares about any more. However, it's not the part that causes the comas to appear, there must be something else.

Comment: You probably saw that async is set to false, so the problem you describe doesn't actually occur

Comment: Why on earth would you want sync requests?